# R Create named matrix by splitting vector

Tags: r, split

So I have a matrix with 2 columns, first the name, second some content like

```
name   content
ID1    1,2,3,4
ID2    1,2,3,4,5,6
ID3    1,2,3
```

The content has different lengths, and splitting the content itself is no problem. After the split I apply a certain function func(x). In the end, I want to receive this output:

```
name    content
ID1     func(1) 
ID1     func(2) 
ID1     func(3) 
ID1     func(4) 
ID2     func(1) 
ID2     func(2) 
ID2     func(3) 
ID2     func(4)
ID2     func(5)
ID2     func(6)
ID3     func(1) 
ID3     func(2) 
ID3     func(3)
```

I searched for certain questions but found nothing fitting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
func <- function(x) multiply_by(x, 100)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(content, convert = T) %>% 
  mutate(content = func(content))
#    name content
# 1   ID1     100
# 2   ID1     200
# 3   ID1     300
# 4   ID1     400
# 5   ID2     100
# 6   ID2     200
# 7   ID2     300
# 8   ID2     400
# 9   ID2     500
# 10  ID2     600
# 11  ID3     100
# 12  ID3     200
# 13  ID3     300
```